How do I exclude cases from a filter in a multi-filter syntax?
Not remotely an SPSS guy at all here so forgive the basicness of all this...
I want to search a large column of long strings (several English sentences) for certain strings. On the SPSS syntax file I received to do this, it's notated thus:
COMPUTE keyword = 0 .
IF ((CHAR.INDEX (column1,'HAT') > 0 |
(CHAR.INDEX (column1, 'HOT') > 0 |
[...]
(CHAR.INDEX (column1, 'CAT') > 0)) keyword = 1 .
EXECUTE.

Now I don't really know what's going on with any of that but it seems to work and that's good enough. What I want to do is complicate some of those lines of code because they're returning too many results. So, for example, I want to capture rows where column1 contains the string HAT but I'm not interested in the word CHAT, which as things stand I get. However, a cell that contains CHAT will be something I want to filter if it also happens to contains the string HOT.
So in other words: I want to see 'I LIKE MY HAT' in my filtered data but not 'I LIKE TO CHAT,' and I do want to see 'MY CAT HAS A HAT.' (Technically I also want to see 'I CHAT IN THIS HAT', but the nature of the data means I don't need to worry about this.)
Is this clear at all?
Thanks in advance!
I've searched around for information on what code I should be using, but I don't know where to start searching. A 'but not' filter?

One simple way to do this would be to use a space within the quote like this:
IF ((CHAR.INDEX(column1,' HAT') > 0

Now HAT will be included, CHAT will not.
To take into account the possibility HAT appears at the beginning or the end of the string, you can use this:
IF ((CHAR.INDEX(concat(" ",column1," "),' HAT ') > 0

This will not work if there are also additional charachters like here: "TAKE OFF YOUR HAT."
The simplest way to work around that is to remove all non letter charachters from column1 before looking for your HAT. So:
string column1alt (a200)./*make sure this is wider then the original column1 .
compute column1alt=concat(" ",column1," ").
do repeat chr="." "," ";" "!" "?" """" "*" "/" ./*add other charachters if needed.
   compute column1alt=replace(column1alt, chr, " ").
end repeat.

Now you can simply use:
IF ((CHAR.INDEX(column1alt,' HAT ') > 0


Aha that's very clever! Thank you!

I've tried the below, and it seems to work; but please do let me know if it's inefficient or wrong. (Bizarrely, it seems to return different results each time I run it, but I'm hoping that's an unrelated issue.)
COMPUTE keyword = 0.
IF (((CHAR.INDEX (column1,'HAT') > 0) AND (CHAR.INDEX (column1,'CHAT') = 0)) |
(CHAR.INDEX (column1, 'HOT') > 0 |
[...]
(CHAR.INDEX (column1, 'CAT') > 0)) keyword = 1.
EXECUTE.

The difference is in line 1: it now says "Return rows which have 'HAT' in column1 and which don't have 'CHAT' in column1."

(1) use (CHAR.INDEX (column1,'CHAT') = 0)   (2) put another pair of parentheses around "HAT and CHAT" so you dont confuse the "and"s and the "or"s.
